# Family Hotels in Ireland?

Tags: accommodation, hotels, ireland

My family and I are traveling to Meath in May 2013 and would like advice on a list of great hotels specifically 4 star range close to tourist attractions. Can anyone help us?

So far I looked at Ardboyne Hotel http://www.ardboynehotel.com/ardboyne-accommodation.html

Comment: http://www.tripadvisor.fr/HACSearch?geo=186628#02,1363782040573,cb:Azfc_4,rad:S0,sponsors:A I preselected 4 star hotels for Meath county. On the right there is a map link, with the option of showing where activities are.

Comment: @Adriana Click on the American or British Flags to convert the above mentioned site into english, unless your french is fairly fluent.

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Please review the [FAQ](http://travel.stackexchange.com/faq) on asking questions and getting answers on this site.  The list questions are generally considered non-constructive, so you might have to narrow down the criteria in terms of attractions to visit and the hotel features.  Normally http://www.kayak.com, http://www.tripadvisor.com, http://www.priceline.com would be the starting points for a broad search.

Comment: Where are you going in Meath? What are you going to see? Are you hiring a car (I presume so). Meath is beside Dublin city, so you can include that in your search.

Comment: Sorry, but I voted to close as being not constructive. Asking for family hotels are better asked at a forum on Ireland, booking.com or just google